# How would I iterate through an array of colors so the color changes each mouseclick?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, for-loop

So I want to iterate through an array of colors upon mouseclick and when it reaches the end of the array go back to the 0 space in the array.

```
 private Color _color = Color.BLACK;
 private Color[] _arrayOfColors = new Color[]{Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK};

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(_color);
    g.drawRect(_x, _y, _size, _size);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mev)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<_arrayOfColors.length; i++)
    {
        _color = _arrayOfColors[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would rather use an `enum`, which the appropriate methods to cycle through the values of the enum, to give the next colour in the list.

Comment: You need to repaint after you iterate through each colour. Also add a delay if you actually want to see it happening...

Comment: Where would the repaint() method be located?

Comment: Within the loop after the colour is changed

Comment: I meant what class is the repaint method located in? JPanel?

Comment: @LostSchemer yes, JPanel

Answer (score 1):

```
Color[] colors = new Color[10]; //your array of colors
Color currentColor; //current color being displayed
int index = 0; //IMPORTANT: prevents your loop from starting at 0 each time

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
     currentColor = colors[index <= colors.length-1? index : index = 0]; //picks next color
     index++; //increases index (prepares for next mouse click)
     repaint(); //paint with new color
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
     g.setColor(currentColor);
     g.drawRect(_x, _y, _size, _size);
 }
```

`currentColor = colors[index <= colors.length-1? index : index = 0];` might seem tricky at first, but let me break it down:

`index <= colors.length-1? index : index = 0` is called a ternary operator. It's a 3 step process

1. Ask a question: `index <= colors.length-1?` (boolean)
2. Set a value to return if question is true
3. Set a value to return if question is false

Our index starts at 0. Since 0 <= 9 (colors.length-1), it will return index. `currentColor = colors[index];`

Although, lets say our index is at 10. Since our array only goes from 0-9, we need to set it back to 0 before using it. `currentColor = colors[index = 0];`

Answer (score 0):

I used this on a canvas project recently. 'i' will cycle the colour array below from 0 to its length infinitely. Hopefully this may help you.

```
var i = 0;
var colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

function mouseClick(){

    var _currColour =  colours[i % colours.length];

    i++;

    return _currColour;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an attribute to track the index of the current color:

```
private int index = 0;
```

Then, in your `mousePressed` event handler, increment this index, taking care of possible `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mev) {
    _color = _arrayOfColors[index];
    index = (index + 1) % _arrayOfColors.length;
}
```